# Can't set property src of a null even though DOM is ready

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, null

So basically I have this table with six images in it for a nice image gallery.  On the nav bar on the bottom I have a javascript function that is supposed to use an array of image file sources to change the individual tags of the image elements in the table when the user clicks.  All of the javascript is supposed to execute when the DOM is ready.  The problem is that when I try to click on the nav bar at the bottom I get the "cannot set src value of a null" which makes me thing that the array isn't working right or it isn't calling the elements the way it is supposed to.

This is the PHP script that creates the table, pulls the images, and sticks them into the javascript array when the DOM is ready,  I have a sneaking suspicion that part of the problem is that the code won't execute unless I include two `</script>`'s after the part that should create the javascript array.

```
<?php

$directory = 'images/gallery/';
$files1 = scandir($directory);
$length = count($files1);
echo "<script $( document ).ready(function() {";
$y = 2;
for ($x = 0; $x < $length-2; $x++) {
echo "images[$x] = 'Images/gallery/$files1[$y]';";
$y= $y + 1;
}
echo "});";
echo"</script>";
echo"</script>";
echo "<table><tr>";
for ($i = 2; $i <= 7; $i++) {
if ($i == 5) {
    echo "</tr><tr>";
}
echo "<td class='galleryImageWrapper'><a href='images/gallery/$files1[$i]' data-lightbox='Gallery'><img id='$i' src='images/gallery/$files1[$i]'></a></td>";
}
echo "</tr></table>";
echo "<div id='galleryNavWrapper'><div onclick='advanceLeft()' id='leftbutton'>&#8656;  </div><ul id='galleryNav'>";
for ($i = 1; $i <= ($length / 6); $i++) {
echo "<li onclick='galleryNavButton(this.value)'>$i</li>";
}
echo '</ul><div id="rightButton" onclick = "advanceRight()">&#8658;</div>';
?>
```

This the HTML Code

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Perspective by Daniel Streich</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scripts/css.css">
    <link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lightbox-2.6.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var i = 0;
        var images = new Array();
        /*
         $( document ).ready(function() {
         document.write("well this be working");
         });*/
        function advanceLeft() {

            if (i == 0) {
                return false;
            } else {
                i = i - 6;
                for (var x = i; x <= 5; x++) {
                    document.getElementById(x).src = images[x];
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        function advanceRight() {
            if (i == images.length - 1) {
                return false;
            } else {
                i = i + 6;
                for (var x = i; x <= 5; x++) {
                    document.getElementById(x).src = images[x];
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        function galleryNavButton(newId) {
            i = i - ((i - newId) * 6);
            for (var x = i; i <= 5; x++) {
                document.getElementById(x).src = images[x];
                return true;
            }

        }

    </script>

    <?php
    $active = "Art";
    include ('menu.php');
    ?>

    <div class="wrapperRegular">
        <p class="bigTitle">
            Perspective by Daniel
        </p>
        <p class='actualText'>
            TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST
            TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST
        </p>
        <?php
        include ('gallery.php');
        ?>
        <br>
        <div id="footer">
            Copyright &#169; Perspective by Daniel
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

If anyone can figure this out, I would be extremely thankful since I can't get it for the life of me.

Comment: Numeric IDs, terrible idea. Why don't you debug the value of `i` when it doesn't work? Should be pretty obvious at that point.

Comment: Also, you have a pretty nasty syntax error with `<script $( document ).ready(function() {`

Comment: I'm using numeric IDs because they are generated through a php script, I don't like using them, but I couldn't figure out a better way of doing it.  How would you suggest I debug it?  I tried putting a couple of document.write(i)'s int the document but nothing happened

Comment: Added JQuery example to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `<script>` contents with the following:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 var i = 0;
        var images = new Array();
        /*
         $( document ).ready(function() {
         document.write("well this be working");
         });*/
        function advanceLeft() {

            if (i == 0) {
                return false;
            } else {
                i = i - 6;
                for (var x = i; x <= 5; x++) {
                    document.getElementById(x).src = images[x];
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        function advanceRight() {
            if (i == images.length - 1) {
                return false;
            } else {
                i = i + 6;
                for (var x = i; x <= 5; x++) {
                    document.getElementById(x).src = images[x];
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        function galleryNavButton(newId) {
            i = i - ((i - newId) * 6);
            for (var x = i; i <= 5; x++) {
                document.getElementById(x).src = images[x];
                return true;
            }

        }
});
```

Example using jQuery to handle clicks:
    echo '⇒';
Becomes:
    echo '⇒';

And in your JQuery script you would just do:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        var i = 0;
        var images = new Array();
        /* This is how you would handle the click */
        $('#rightButton').click(function(){
            advanceRight();
        });
        function advanceLeft() {

            if (i == 0) {
                return false;
            } else {
                i = i - 6;
                for (var x = i; x <= 5; x++) {
                    document.getElementById(x).src = images[x];
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        function advanceRight() {
            if (i == images.length - 1) {
                return false;
            } else {
                i = i + 6;
                for (var x = i; x <= 5; x++) {
                    document.getElementById(x).src = images[x];
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        function galleryNavButton(newId) {
            i = i - ((i - newId) * 6);
            for (var x = i; i <= 5; x++) {
                document.getElementById(x).src = images[x];
                return true;
            }

        }
});
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I tried that and now it says all of my functions are undefined.

Comment: I'm not sure why you don't just do something like this `$('#someidforclickfield').click(function(){ advanceRight() });` instead of using a bunch of onclick's. If you'd like I can update the answer to show you what that would be like

Comment: I tried doing something like that initially but I absolutely butchered the syntax and one of my friends said I'd be better off doing it like this, if could show me that would be great.

Comment: I added a sample click method in there for you (edited my existing answer). Hope that helps. I added a comment to it as well. Let me know if that works.